# No notification to update to latest Joomla version

Tags: joomla-2.5, update, cache, one-click-updates, versions

I am managing a site powered by Joomla 2.5 (**online** installation) and hosted on Joomla **free** hosting.

Only since the latest 2-3 months it happens that I don't receive anymore the emails reminding to update to current version (2.5.24 when I write).

Furthermore - I should say *Above all* - in the same period, when I log in to administration, it says there are no updates available and that the current stable version is 2.5.19. These two things I have empathized in red here:

[image: Update notification]

Is this situation related to J2.5 end-of-life term in late 2014?

Can I do something to handle the update "manually" on admin side or somewhere else online?

I remark that this problem occurred to me only in the latest months, never before.

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Do you try purging the cache before trying to find updates? No, that as nothing to do with Joomla coming toward its EOL as update are found by reading an XML file located on the Joomla server which the Joomla will still update until the EOL is reached. Im not sure on your server settings as they will most likely vary a lot from.paid hosting but in the mean time, either contact your hosting provider, or download the latest Joomla update package from the official site and extract it via FTP in the root directory

Comment: @Lodder: What you mention in the last line of your comment is method C in this link? http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Upgrading_from_an_existing_version Thank you

Comment: Yes, however I believe you will also be able to use method B. You may get a PHP timeout though as the update package is rather big and free hosting starts crying with large files

Comment: @Lodder: Yes, plan B cut the problems. It showed an error message when uploading but now panel shows ve. 2.5.24 with the updated release date. Even if we didn't manage yet to explain this change in the "service", you should post an answer.

Comment: @moomoochoo: yeah the title is now improved. The most important matter (shown in the picture) is with the admin panel, rather than with _email_ notifications. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is usually caused by the cache mechanisms in Joomla. It has nothing to do with the Joomla 2.5. eol.

**Clear Cache** and **purge expired cache** from the **maintenance menu**, and also it usually helps if you go to **Extensions Manager -> update / manage** and **Clear/Refresh the cahce** for the extensions there.

Then go to the Joomla Update Component and see if it shows the available update. As always, have a **backup** in place before performing any updates.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to the extension manager and select the update tab
2. Click on purge cache
3. Click on find updates
4. Go to Control Panel. The joomla updater will now report an update available.

Comment: As in the answer by FFrewin, clearing cache and purging expired does not give any effect in my case. I'll post an update to the question in the weekend...

Comment: @MattAllegro I also tried clearing and purging through maintenance menu but it didn't work. The one that it did was going to the extension manager and purging cache in there.

Comment: I'll check this out, to make sure, and post further ...as soon as 2.5.28 is released (2.5.27 is out when I write).

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, Joomla itself does not send out update notifications by email. My guess is that you have a third-party extension for this. [Akeeba Backup](http://akeebabakup.com) used to send out update notifications, but I think they stopped due to the amount of support tickets caused by this function. It should still be available, but you might have to enable it manually.

There are other update notification tools available at JED, like [CUpdater](https://compojoom.com/joomla-extensions/cupdater-notification-system).